# How can I fix laravel named routes to get the proper result

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-code-404, laravel-9

I'm a beginner with laravel and trying to figure out the routes. I searched the web but provided solutions don't help, so maybe you guys will be able to shed some light.
So below is my routes file (web.php)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'home']);
    Route::get('dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');

    Route::get('billing', function () {
        return view('billing');
    })->name('billing');

    Route::get('profile', function () {
        return view('profile');
    })->name('profile');

    Route::get('rtl', function () {
        return view('rtl');
    })->name('rtl');

    Route::get('user-management', function () {
        return view('laravel-examples/user-management');
    })->name('user-management');

    Route::get('tables', function () {
        return view('tables');
    })->name('tables');

    Route::get('virtual-reality', function () {
        return view('virtual-reality');
    })->name('virtual-reality');

    Route::get('static-sign-in', function () {
        return view('static-sign-in');
    })->name('sign-in');

    Route::get('static-sign-up', function () {
        return view('static-sign-up');
    })->name('sign-up');

    Route::get('/logout', [SessionsController::class, 'destroy']);
    Route::get('/user-profile', [InfoUserController::class, 'create']);
    Route::post('/user-profile', [InfoUserController::class, 'store']);
    Route::get('/login', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('sign-up');
    
    Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'create']);
    Route::get('/user-list', [RegisterController::class, 'index'])->name('user-list');
    Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'store']);
    //Route::delete('user-destroy', [RegisterController::class, 'destroy'])->name('user-destroy');
    Route::resource('users', RegisterController::class);
    //Route::get('/viehicle-types', [ViehicleTypeController::class, 'index']);
    // Route::resource('viehicle-types', ViehicleTypeController::class);
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin|manager']], function () {
        
        Route::resource('viehicle-types', ViehicleTypeController::class);
        Route::resource('addon-types', AddonTypeController::class);
        Route::resource('addons', AddonController::class);
        Route::resource('job-types', JobTypeController::class);
        Route::resource('jobs', JobController::class);
        Route::resource('viehicles', ViehicleController::class);
        Route::get('/finished-jobs/registerSelectJobType', [FinishedJobController::class, 'registerSelectJobType'])->name('xxxx');
        Route::get('/finished-jobs/registerSelectJob/{jobTypeId}', [FinishedJobController::class, 'registerSelectJob'])->name('yyyy');
        Route::resource('finished-jobs', FinishedJobController::class);
    });
});
```

My problem is that some of the name routes won't work.
Mainly these 2 don't work and display a 404 Error:

```
Route::get('/finished-jobs/registerSelectJobType', [FinishedJobController::class, 'registerSelectJobType'])->name('xxxx');
Route::get('/finished-jobs/registerSelectJob/{jobTypeId}', [FinishedJobController::class, 'registerSelectJob'])->name('yyyy');
```

What is strange that when I check the routes:

```
$url=route('xxxx');  
echo "The url is : " .$url;
```

I get the proper URL that works when entered in the web browser.
So I can't figure it out if anyone can help I will be greatful.

Cheers
HT

Comment: A 404 error is not only related to routes. It could be an "Implicit Binding" error too. The easiest way to check is inserting a "dd('a')" in the first line in your "registerSelectJobType" and "registerSelectJob" methods, in the "FinishedJobController" and remove all the function parameters. if you see the "dd" result, it means that your routes are fine, and the problem is with the paremeters in the function.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but I don't see the dd result. Still 404 :(

Comment: Ok solved I misunderstood the concept of named routes...